# Signed Measure Decomposition Integral

Tags: measure-theory

**Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and f integrable (on it). The signed measure $v$ is defined by
$v(A)=\int 1_A f d \mu,$  $\text{   }$$A \in \mathcal{A}$.
Determine a unique decomposition $v=v^+-v^-$ in two to each other singular measures $v^+$ and $v^-$.**

Two measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are singular together, if the sets $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$ exists mit $A \cup B=X,A \cap B=\emptyset,\mu_1(A)=0$ and $\mu_2(B)=0$.

*My suggestion (basically i haven't any idea because very unknown topic):*

$v(A\cup B)=\int 1_{A\cup B}fd\mu=\int_{A\cup B}f^+d\mu-\int_{A\cup B}f^-d\mu$

If i now could assume that $\mu_2(A)=0=\mu_1(B)$ is a precondition, then i would say:
$=\int_A f^+d\mu_2-\int_B f^-d\mu_1=v^+(A)-v^-(B)$

What is the right solution?

Answer (score 1):

$\nu^{+}(E)=\int 1_E f^{+}d\mu$ and $\nu^{-}(E)=\int 1_E f^{-}d\mu$ defines two measures with $\nu^{+}-\nu^{-}=\nu$. Let $A=\{x: f(x) \geq 0\}$ and $B=\{x: f (x) <0\}$. Then $A\cup B=X$ and $A\cap B$ is empty. Also $\nu^{+}(E)=\nu (A \cap E)$, $\nu^{-}(E)=\nu (B \cap E)$, $\nu^{+}(B)=0$ and  $\nu^{-}(A)=0$. Hence $\nu^{+}\perp \nu^{-}$

Comment: Thanks for the solution. So A and B are preconditions.  I thought that there is a more non trivial general derivation (because of the conceptual formulation) , but it isn't that difficult.